# AWS OpsWorks: how to set the default EBS volume size per layer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

I am sure I am missing something obvious, but I can't find a way to set the default EBS volume  size per layer. Every instance I boot on this layer has a 10GB volume by default.

In the Layer configuration pane I try to add an EBS volume with the size I need, but it won't let me mount it on "/".

I need this extra size for my app installed at /srv/www but the doc says one should not mount a volume at this point:

> Do not mount Amazon EBS volumes to the following mount points. If the
>   instance is rebooted, autofs might use them to mount an ephemeral
>   device instead of your volume.
>
> /srv/www

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mount volumes at /, that's the root.
Unfortunately you can't set the root device size in OpsWorks.
But you could mount a volume somewhere else like `/mnt/www` and symlink there.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing something like that... It is a pity though that it can't be done a bit more easily.

Comment: I will take this as a feature request. :)

Comment: @spangenberg I was looking for this exact thing. We store logs for a few days and they go over limit once in a while. Would love to have instances start with a little more space. Thanks.

Comment: I understand your problem. In the meantime please mount a EBS volume to /var/log or wherever you store your logs.

Comment: @spangenberg, I really hope it's coming sometime soon since it would also FINALLY allow the attachment of a General Purpose or PIOPS **SSD** root device!

Comment: It would be a really good feature. Right now for stacks with many instances in a non-MySQL DB cluster (defined in a layer) for example, you can't just add an instance to the layer and expect your defined automation to take care of everything, since 8 GB is too small for most DB instances. It would be nice to at least be able to automate this via a recipe somewhere.

Comment: @DanielSpangenberg quite an issue for us as well. We're using opsworks to fire up new instances that can be used by a kubernetes cluster, where having multiple docker daemon restarts (when moving to `mnt`) would cause issues. Anyway.

Answer (score 7):

At the moment of this writing you can't change the default root volume size using OpsWorks. However, when using the API's [create-instance command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/opsworks/create-instance.html) you can provide a [block device mapping](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html) (like on EC2) and define the size.

For example you can create a file with the contents below, and call it "instance.json" for convenience:

```
{
    "InstanceType": "c4.large", 
    "RootDeviceType": "ebs", 
    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
        {
            "DeviceName": "ROOT_DEVICE", 
            "Ebs": {
                "VolumeSize": 20, 
                "VolumeType": "gp2", 
                "DeleteOnTermination": true
            }
        }
    ] 
}
```

And you can then execute a command like the one below to create an instance with the desired root volume size, using the file and replacing the correct stack and layer IDs:

```
aws opsworks create-instance --cli-input-json file://./instance.json --stack-id <stack-id-number-here> --layer-ids <one-or-more-layer-id-numbers-here>
```

If you prefer a oneliner, though a bit clunkier:

```
aws opsworks create-instance --stack-id <stack-id-number-here> --layer-ids <one-or-more-layer-id-numbers-here> --instance-type <e.g. c4.large> --block-device-mappings '[{"DeviceName":"ROOT_DEVICE","Ebs":{"VolumeType":"gp2","VolumeSize":20}}]'
```

Please note that this procedure only works when **creating** an instance, and you can't modify it after that, except manually.

Comment: Can I achieve this with CloudFormation?

Comment: @Casper this is not achievable through CloudFormation. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opsworks-instance.html) you can see that there's no support for _BlockDeviceMappings_.

However you could use [Custom Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-opsworks-instance.html) to invoke a [Lambda function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) to create/modify/update those resources.

Comment: So you're saying I need to spin up an instance first, and then modify the root volume?

Comment: @Casper, were you able to achieve this with CloudFormation?

Comment: @ManishJoshi not atm, I contacted AWS support and this is a feature request.